# Problem getting FRFeedbackReporter.sh script to work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

I'm using FeedbackReporter framework from https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter.

Everything is working great, except that I'm trying to implement a FRFeedbackReporter.sh script to capture some additional configuration data that isn't in the standard report.  I'll I really want to do is include the contents of a plist into the report.  But I can't seem to get anything to show up at all.  Even a simple script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
```

doesn't generate any output.

I know the script is running, because I see this in the console:

```
2011-08-30 11:22:14.948 XXXX[39948:e563] Script exit code = -1
```

I'm wondering if I missed some step to get the script output included in the feedback report.

joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say much about contributed email script but the "Shell" section of the UI should show the output of your shell command. Indeed that log line suggests it is trying to run the script.

https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter/blob/master/Sources/Main/FRFeedbackController.m#L226

If it does not show anything - then there is a problem. The exit code of -1 actually already suggests that. Digging deeper you can see that FR explicitly return -1 if the script is not executable

https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter/blob/master/Sources/Main/FRCommand.m#L126

So I would think - maybe your script needs a

```
chmod a+x FRFeedbackReporter.sh
```